# Iterative executing select layer by attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a Shapefile. There  is a field "YEAR" (range 2000 - 2015) in the attribute table.

I want to select layer base on different year and save as a new layer and don't know how to add a loop into following model.

[image]

---

I try to add a for loop.

[image]

The error occurs.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the 'Iterate Feature Selection' iterator.  Replace 'Select Layer by Attribute' with this iterator.  Set the group by field to "YEAR".

[image]

[image]

Iterate Feature Selection:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-selection.htm

To add a query to the output of the iterator, add a 'Make Feature Layer' tool and set the expression as follows.  This is assuming that YEAR field is numeric.  If you're using a string field, you'll need to add single quotes around %Value% like this '%Value':

[image]

Make Feature Layer settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And how can I select features where "YEAR <  %Value%"

Comment: I edited my answer to include the query.

Comment: Where can I find the last window

Comment: That is the settings window for Make Feature Layer.

Comment: If your years are stored as strings you'll need to add single quotes - '%Value%'